# How to draw line in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, canvas, line

I am an Android beginner. As you can see in the picture, some `ImageView` in the  `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]

I want to draw lines like red lines in the picture. At the same time, I don't want to change picture location.

[image]

At the start, I want to customise my `ConstraintLayout` and overwrite `onDraw()` method. But it still not work.

Comment: Hey Congrats on starting to develop android. But Usually ConstraintLayout isn't really used. Try using RelativeLayout instead or LinearLayout is what I always use.

Comment: ConstraintLayout is the replacement for RelativeLayout and is the google-recommended view to use

Answer (score 0):

you need to know where the location of those line starting and ending points. let's say (starting point - x1,y1 ending point - x2,y2). In code add this. you need to have a canvas

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
```

then draw line

```
Paint paintLine= new Paint();
paintLine.setAntiAlias(true);
paintLine.setColor(Color.RED);
paintLine.setStrokeWidth(5);
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paintLine);
```

place it in constraint layout

```
 yourconstraintlayout.addView(canvas,0);
 set.clone(yourconstraintlayout);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already solved it using another method.Anyway，thank you.